# How do I add support for "Hindi Remington layout", in Windows-8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, language, typing

How do I add support for "Hindi Remington layout", in Windows-8.

I tried looking in the language option located in the control-pannel.  However there are only 2  Hindi keyboard layouts ( Devanagari - INSCRIPT  and Hindi Traditional ) present.

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted the keyboard manufacturer? I would expect them to provide support if there is none in the OS. Otherwise, there is software around to allow you to modify or create a keyboard layout.

Comment: http://bhashaindia.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/Downloads/IME/Indic3/helpfiles/Hindi%20Indic%20Input%203-User%20Guide.pdf